# array_rand function returns empty sometimes

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, random

I want to make a little service.The service's main idea is to show one record from mysql table and it makes this per click at randomly.

Here is the code that i wrote:

```
<?php
require'connection.php';

$dbQueryFirst = $nesnePDO->prepare("SELECT CategoryID FROM Categories");
$dbQueryFirst->execute();   
while ($resultsFirst = $dbQueryFirst->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $getidFirst[] = $resultsFirst;
    $puppet = array_rand($getidFirst);
    if ($puppet == null && empty($puppet)) 
    {
        shuffle($getidFirst);       
    }       
}

$rndID = $puppet;

$dbQuerySecond = $nesnePDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID = :CategoryID");
$dbQuerySecond->bindParam(":CategoryID",$rndID);
$dbQuerySecond->execute();
$resultsSecond = $dbQuerySecond->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultsSecond);
?>
```

First query is,get id's from db and take them into array.Second query,get the random id from the previous query's result and show the entire row of relevant id.And I got stuck at random function.
If I need to explain this work with percentage for to be more clearly,

- Works well and get results %70
- get empty %20
- get null array `[]` %10

I wanted the show the screenshots but system didn't give the permission because of my reputation.So,the final statement as usual,"I'm not so good at PHP.Any idea?" Honestly,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should wait for array to get filled inside your while loop and then get random value from it.

```
while ($resultsFirst = $dbQueryFirst->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $getidFirst[] = $resultsFirst;     
}

$puppet = array_rand($getidFirst);
$rndID = $getidFirst[$puppet];
```

Also, you can get random entry directly from your database without using php.

```
$dbQueryFirst = $nesnePDO->prepare("SELECT CategoryID FROM Categories ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$dbQueryFirst->execute();  
$rndID = $dbQueryFirst->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

By the way, you should be getting your CategoryID like so

```
$rndID['CategoryID']
```

Comment: The code block that you wrote returns false.Absolute.The second advice about sql querying,haven't tried yet.Because I googled about it's perform not as good as you may expected.But I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Cat you write the result of var_dump($rndID)?

Comment: first block same as @splash58's. for second part,echoing `$rndID['CategoryID']` isn't working.

Comment: What about var_dump($getidFirst) then? You should really check your database table.

Comment: All right I got it.The old table haven't got empty spaces but I couldn't trust it.I drop the table and added a new one.And I added new records.Somehow it works.Both of your answers were helpful.Thank you

Comment: @14kubat Yea, that was actually expected. It would be nice of you to up vote the answers that helped you and pick any answer as correct one to close this question completely.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc

```
When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry
```

Second, $resultsFirst, i think, is array you need take item of it `$resultsFirst['CategoryID']`

So, use

```
while ($resultsFirst = $dbQueryFirst->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
    $getidFirst[] = $resultsFirst['CategoryID'];
}

$puppet = array_rand($getidFirst);
$rndID = $getidFirst[$puppet];
```

Comment: I tried,but sometimes still returns empty value.It's just increase the percentage that I explained in the question :)

Comment: if you add echo $rndID; after my code you should any catid every time. Test please, that it is so

Comment: sorry i wrote but i actually made it in the wrong block of code.yes it returns but some id's null.why is that?

Comment: It maybe only if array contains empty value. You easy can test this. If so, look into your db

Comment: All right I got it.The old table haven't got empty spaces but I couldn't trust it.I drop the table and added a new one.And I added new records.Somehow it works.Both of your answers were helpful.Thank you

Comment: It is well. Good luck! You can accept the answer if it was heplful